# How to select a drop down option which is inside a iframe whose id changes dynamically?

Tags: java, iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am writing a selenium script to automate a web-page. I need to select a value from the dropdown .This dropdown is inside an iFrame. I am finding it difficult to navigate to dropdown option's.

This is the Dropdown Image I am referring to and its respective inspect element view

[image]

Below is my xml code:

```
<input id="sfdcIFrameOrigin" type="hidden" value="https://cs83.salesforce.com" name="sfdcIFrameOrigin"/>
<div id="ep" class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd bEditBlock bLayoutBlock secondaryPalette">
<div class="pbHeader">
<div class="pbBody">
<div id="errorDiv_ep" class="pbError" style="display: none">
<div class="pbSubsection">
<table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="labelCol requiredInput">
<td class="data2Col" colspan="3">
<div class="requiredInput">
<div class="requiredBlock"/>
<select id="p3" name="p3">
<option selected="selected"  value="0124E00000005wt">Organisation</option>
<option value="0124E00000005x8">Person Account</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="last detailRow">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pbBottomButtons">
<div class="pbFooter secondaryPalette">
</div>
```

I used :

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ext-comp-1141");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='p3']/option[1]")).sendKeys("Organisation");
```

It gave me an error- **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 10.12 seconds**

Please help me script - selecting an option from the above dropdown. 
Awaiting your help

Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess organization is already selected

Comment: can you do one thing can you post complete html source code including iframe above parent tags or if possible plz share the link certainly i will figure what is the issue

Comment: @rajNishKuMar - Yes, option 1 is the default value of the dropdown hence it is selected by default. Dropdown is inside an iframe and I am missing something in switching to iframe. Please suggest how to access these dropdown elements that are inside an iframe

Comment: can you post the iframe source code i just want too look at the various attributes of the iframe

Comment: @rajNishKuMar : I guess i figured out why I was getting error message . My iframe id is changing dyanmically . I have tried contains () and start with() attribute  . 
   WebElement new_frame=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'ext-comp-')]"));     . even after using this I am getting Unable to locate element error. I am sure its because of the dynamically changing id attribute. Can u suggest any other way to locate this iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i guess i have figured out the problem that you are getting i am sure there are multiple i frame available on your webpage

```
// you are moving to wrong iframe below 
    driver.switchTo().frame("ext-comp-1141");
```

// instead move to frame in your code as when you will see your screen shot then in the developers option before highlight you will see the i-frame name like below

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ext-comp-1118.x-border..");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='p3']/option[1]")).sendKeys("Organisation");
```

it will work i am very sure

Comment: ok do one thing instead of using sendkeys plz use Select as answerd by @ Guy